# why should i set this property, getsture.scale = 1?

Tags: iphone

```
-(void)pinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gesture

{
   if((gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) ||
      (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded))
   {
       self.scale *= gesture.scale;
       gesture.scale = 1;
   }
}
```

hello i'm studying iOS.
but i have a question, which is the last line of this code.

gesture.scale = 1

i'm going to get this called repeatedly every time it changed.
but why should i reset it to 1 ?

i really don't know about this meaning.
help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that what's happening is that `self.scale` is the cumulative scaling factor: each time your UIPinchGestureRecognizer is called, the total scaling factor is updated by the current scaling amount (by multiplying them together).

Since that scaling has then been applied to the total, the scaling for the gesture is reset to `1`, so you don't apply the same transformation more than once.

Comment: thank you. but i still have a question. you said it's the cumulative scaling factor. then why didn't it set to 0 ? why 1 ?

Comment: Because it's a multiplicative attribute - a scale of 1 means "no change", a scale of 1.1 means "10% bigger", and so forth. For example, if the user pinches in to half size then back out to the initial location, you'll get successive updates of ".5" and "2.0", so when you're done self.scale will be `.5 * 2.0` == `1.0` (same size as you started).